# What controls the 'severity' of ApexPages.addMessages(exception)?

Tags: visualforce, controller, bestpractice, error-messages

I'm trying to crystallize out some 'best practises' for Visualforce Page exception handling.

I think, at a minimum, a page should look something like this:

```
<apex:page controller="PageController">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!NOT(HasFatalMessages)}" />
</apex:page>
```

- always present is `apex:pageMessages`
- when a fundamental misconfiguration is detected, the UI is hidden to prevent data entry

Then the controller class might look something like this:

```
public with sharing class PageController {

    public Boolean getHasFatalMessages() {
        return ApexPages.hasMessages(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL);
    }

    public PageController() {
        try {
            //check org configuration required
            //for this page (for example, custom
            //settings, field set members, etc)
        } catch (SomeDomainLayerException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't for the life of me work out how **`ApexPages.addMessages(e)`** determines severity. It always seems to be `ApexPages.Severity.ERROR` no matter what. How can I change that?

Or should I throw an uncaught exception to blow up the whole page, indicating bigger problems?

Comment: could you share your "best practices" for Visualforce page exception handling ?

Comment: @apn feel free to ask as a new question - it may warrant discussion (and therefore not be a good format for SFSE) but will definitely get the attention it deserves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try catching errors as below :

```
catch(Exception e)
        {
            String error = e.getMessage();
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,error));
        }
```

Instead of just doing `ApexPages.addMessages(e);`

Using this in conjunction with Apexpages.hasMessages()

```
if(some_condition){
                        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Info not an error'));
        }
        if(ApexPages.hasMessages(ApexPages.Severity.Info)){
        // do something
        }
```

To set severity dynamically I would use `getTypeName()` and create a map/ custom setting with exception key and severity value

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex230/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm

Comment: Cool. I figured it's a little more wordy, but one really does have to specify the severity and throw domain-specific exceptions in the domain layer. Exceptions do not carry severity.

Comment: As far as I know exception class only carry the exception info and not the severity level, you can make a map/ custom setting that carry severity levels based on exception that might occur.

Comment: I have a comment in some code (that uses `ApexPages.addMessages(e)`) that says: Using this signature method appears to both avoid duplication for errors added to fields in triggers and get declarative errors such as DUPLICATE_VALUE reported albeit in rather basic form e.g. "duplicate value found: cve__Temp__c duplicates value on record with id: 0035000001epEMl". This was in a context where DmlExceptions could be thrown. So ApexPages.addMessages probably contains some useful processing logic that you will lose if you use other patterns.

Comment: plus be aware of this delightful undocumented behavior - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50180/apexpages-addmessage-behavior-inconsistent-by-version

Answer (score 3):

Here are some examples of how to add messages with different severities and how they are outputted:

**Confirm/Success:**

```
ApexPages.addMessage(
     new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Confirm,'Sample Success Message'));
```

[image]

---

**Warning:**

```
ApexPages.addMessage(
    new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Sample Warning Message'));
```

[image]

---

**Informational:**

```
ApexPages.addMessage(
    new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Sample Informational Message'));
```

[image]

---

**Error:**

```
ApexPages.addMessage(
    new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,'Sample Error Message'));
```

[image]

---

There's a great answer in this question that has lots more detail: [Difference between the multiple messaging options in Visualforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8139/difference-between-the-multiple-messaging-options-in-visualforce)

Answer (score -2):

Severity for error message is defined when we add message in to page using our code. See code below for different severity:

```
if(acc.name == '' || acc.name == null)
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please enter Account name'));

      if(acc.AccountNumber == '' || acc.AccountNumber == null)
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter Account number'));

      if(acc.phone == '' || acc.phone == null)
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please enter Account phone'));

      if(acc.site == '' || acc.site == null)
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Please enter Account site'));

      if(acc.industry == '' || acc.industry == null)
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Please enter Account industry'));
```

[image: Error Message with different severity]

For more details see below link:

http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/show-error-message-visualforce-page/

Comment: Ankush, how does this provide more information than the already given answer by BarCotter ?