# Apex:pageMessages Only Displaying First Error on Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, validation, error

I have a visualforce page in which I have set many inputFields as required. When I click save and if no values have been entered for the required fields i do receive an error message

> Error: You must enter a value

beside each field in my form. However I want to display all error messages at the start of my form. If I use `<apex:pagemessages>` the very first required field where no value has been entered is detailed in the `<apex:pagemessages>` component but the remaining errors are not displayed.  If I subsequently enter a value in the first field, on submitting my form the next field error is displayed in `<apex:pagemessages>`

All fields which have no values receive the "Error: You must enter a value" message. Why are all errors not displayed in the `<apex:pageMessages>` component.

I've searched stackoverflow and the Salesforce developer forums but I have not come across an answer to this issue. All posts I've come across so far go into detail about adding custom validation messages in the controller but no solution for the above issue is provided.

Any explanation or suggestions on how to get around this would be welcomed.

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: I'd have to see but it, but how are you building your string ?  Are you using +=?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by building my string?  I don't build any string. I do not write to ApexPageMessages in my Apex class.  Adding required="true" on visualforce page inputFields ensures fields are validated on calling an apex function.

Comment: I had a similar situation here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50180/apexpages-addmessage-behavior-inconsistent-by-version

Answer (score 0):

The apex:pageMessages component automatically de-duplicates messages, and since all of your fields are throwing the same generic `Error: You must enter a value` message, it only appears once. You can confirm this by adding the following to your page constructor:

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'test'));
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'test'));
```

You might try using the `label` attribute of your apex:inputFields (or the `for` attribute on the accompanying apex:outputLabels, if you're using apex:pageBlockSectionItems)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your feedback. I'll look into this today. Regarding the "label" suggestion I'm guessing this wouldn't remove the de-duplication of the messages? I'd still like the messages to appear at the top of the form. Are you suggesting using "labels" can help this also?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes I was, but I just realized that it may not help in this case. Previously, I've had inputs that were using the `required` attribute, with empty values resulting in messy page messages that (if I recall correctly) included the ugly component Ids. Upon using the Label attributes, I would get much cleaner error messages. 
The difference here is that your messages are being suppressed because they're dupes... I wonder if it has to do with being DB vs UI required?